# All our live HTML forms stopped sending data, I'm desperate for any suggestions as to how this could happen

Tags: html, file-upload, upload, liferay

Our portal has been running on Liferay 6.2 for several years. We have many services that use HTML forms (usually written with Alloy UI in Freemarker) to allow users to submit requests. The server code is written in Java and uses the liferay portletrequest objects to return the submit form data.

However, recently these forms suddenly stopped working.

Specifically: if the form includes a file for uploading, then the ActionRequest object does not return any of the form fields as parameters the way it usually does (request.getparameter(paramtername) returns null instead of the string value that the user entered into the form). If the user does not include any files then it works normally.

This doesn't seem to be an issue with the forms or the java code as many forms who's code has not been touched in years suddenly stopped working. What's more this stopped working partway through a day in which we didn't make any changes to the application.

I'm struggling to understand what I'm seeing in the logs. The error messages that feel most promising look like:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly

        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)

        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.portlet.PortletFileUpload.parseRequest(PortletFileUpload.java:109)

        at org.springframework.web.portlet.multipart.CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsPortletMultipartResolver.java:151)

        ... 208 more
```

But I haven't been able to find anything that seems relevant. Another type of error that might be related looks like:

```
10:00:09,095 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-272][FileImpl:422] Unable to extract text from Scan4.JPG
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.jpeg.JpegParser@3e34efc2
```

We've been trying to track down the issue for days now, I'm desperate and out of ideas. Can anyone think of any possible reasons why files would not upload?

Comment: As the problem is certainly located in _some_ code - either your own or Liferay's or a third party's - that hasn't been touched, it still would be valuable to have a [mcve] to reproduce something, and the _full_ stacktrace (e.g. to see if your own portlet is involved or not). Please check [ask] and edit your question with more information.

Comment: Have up updated any software such as liferay recently ?

Comment: @OlafKock I cannot reproduce the issue locally, it only happens on the live production environment. I'm not convinced it's a code issue, I suspect a network issue (the portal is hosted on a third party server) or a configuration issue, but without some idea of what kind of network issue could cause the problem we haven't made any progress on that front.

Comment: @OlafKock As for a stack trace, there literally isn't anything printed to the logs when we try to submit a form (except for if the code complains about receiving no data from the ActionRequest, which is not the root cause of the problem and therefore not worth posting here), and the full stack trace from the day the problem started is 1.3GB so difficult to post and I didn't think it was fair to expect people to look through it.

Comment: @RohitGupta We have not updated any libraries or dependencies or anything. Some minor changes to some specific applications were deployed a few days before the issue started, but the portal worked fine for days afterwards and those changes should not have caused ALL forms in multiple modules to fail.

Comment: The second error seems to because the file uploading/processing terminated, so the file is damaged. So there may be a relevant error earlier than the first one you posted.